# Uikit vertical navbar menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, getuikit

I am trying to create vertical navbar menu with [uikit navbar](https://getuikit.com/docs/navbar).

But it setting automatically top margin for dropdown.
So the dropdown doesn't work properly when it sets top margin.

Here is css and html:

```css
.vertical {
    display: block!important;
    max-width: 200px !important;
}
.vertical  ul.uk-navbar-nav{
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
.vertical ul.uk-navbar-nav li > div.uk-navbar-dropdown
{
 left: 210px !important;
}
.vertical ul.uk-navbar-nav >li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: -20px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="uk-navbar-container vertical uk-navbar" uk-navbar="mode:click;">
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">
        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
            <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent</a>
                <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
                    <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
                        <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Please help about this.

Thanks

Comment: you could try adding `margin-top: unset`

Comment: @rebecca thanks but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.85">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Document</title>

            <!-- UIkit CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/css/uikit.min.css" />
    
            <!-- UIkit JS -->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="uk-container-expand">
                <div class="uk-grid-small uk-grid-collapse uk-grid" uk-height-viewport uk-grid>
                    <div class="uk-width-1-4@s uk-background-muted uk-padding">
                        <nav role="main-navigation">
                            <ul class="uk-nav-default uk-nav-parent-icon" uk-nav>
                              <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                              <li class="uk-parent">
                                  <a href="#">Parent</a>
                                  <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                                      <li>
                                          <a href="#">Sub item</a>
                                          <ul>
                                              <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                                              <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                                          </ul>
                                      </li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li class="uk-parent">
                                  <a href="#">Parent</a>
                                  <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-width-expand@s uk-padding">
                        <main role="content">
                            <p>
                                
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis ornare ex at vulputate. Ut gravida leo arcu, et tincidunt sem vehicula id. Aliquam ornare mollis quam, tincidunt auctor nisi sagittis et. Integer aliquam tellus ac lacus iaculis aliquam. Nulla gravida erat vel justo varius consectetur. Aenean venenatis sed lorem eget bibendum. Sed facilisis non felis id scelerisque. Sed tincidunt ligula in lacus sollicitudin, vel accumsan dolor malesuada. Cras et sapien non ante mattis rhoncus. Ut rutrum rutrum nibh tincidunt pharetra.
    
                                Aliquam quis condimentum urna, nec posuere lectus. In vitae efficitur elit. Phasellus eget lorem dignissim, malesuada lorem non, rutrum ex. Vivamus nec fringilla nisl. Quisque in orci nec mauris tempor sodales eu vitae lectus. In scelerisque eros orci, eu varius magna efficitur at. Etiam molestie turpis vitae vulputate suscipit.
    
                            </p>
                        </main>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Is this suitable for your needs?